# How to disable arrow keys in google autocomplete address search dropdown - React Js

Tags: reactjs, google-places-autocomplete

I have integrated google autocomplete in my React Js project(screenshot attached), when a user enters something in textbox it shows autocomplete address in dropdown. I want to allow user to click on any particular address using mouse only and thus disable arrow keys navigation.
Here is my code on react js

```
const SearchPanel = () => {

    const [state, updateState] = useState(SearchPanelState);
   
    useEffect(() => {
        var placeData = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('searchLocation'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(placeData, 'place_changed', function () {
            const googleResponse = placeData.getPlace();
            updateState({...state, types: googleResponse.types, placeId : googleResponse.place_id});
        });
        
    });

    return (
        <Fragment>
            
            <div className="search_panel clearfix">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Address... " id="searchLocation"/>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary ripple" type="button" style={{background:'#ff3366'}}
                        onClick={() => functionToRedirect(state, updateState)}>Search
                </button>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
```

[image]

Comment: That's not good for accessibility. Why would you want to remove keyboard nav?

Comment: Let's just say, its a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what you receive in event object and each key on keyboard is associated with character code identify that code and compare with one you receive in event object and then simply return so handler won’t do anything giving you a feel keys are disabled

Comment: Aniruddha, I already tried that but it seems to be not working. Can you provide some code here.